# Get values from select items with same name

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML form with a variable number of select fields. Each select field represents the same category, so I named all the selects like `mySelect[]`. The code I wrote for getting the values is bellow:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['mySelect']); $i++) {
    echo $_POST['mySelect'][$i];
}
```

But I don't get any results. What is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: nothing is wrong in your sample. You will have to show the form and/or a dump of your $_POST.

Comment: what you wrote seems ok,try to echo count($_POST['mySelect']) to see if it has anything or not.if it has something the problem is some where else.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text name="item[]" value="item1" />
<input type="text name="item[]" value="item2" />
<input type="text name="item[]" value="item3" />

<pre>
<?php print_r( $_POST[ 'item' ] ); ?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do:

```
var_dump($_POST['mySelect']);
```

Also, what about using foreach instead of for:

```
foreach ($_POST['mySelect'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: var_dump returns `string(5) "Array"`

Comment: @Psyche: So `$_POST['mySelect']` contains a string `"Array"` and not an array ;)

Comment: is there any processing of $_POST before this (perhaps in a framework, or perhaps a stripslashes)?  Something's doing $_POST['mySelect'] = (string) $_POST['mySelect'];